# Prevent background color change when the graph data changed in scale view at apex chart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, background-color, linechart, apexcharts

I created Apexchart (line chart) components with date filter picker.

The chart is dynamic based on series.

```
function RenderChart({ series, xaxis }: { series: any; xaxis?: any }) {
  const chartOptions = {
    options: {
      chart: { zoom: { enabled: false } },
      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth' as 'smooth' | 'straight' | 'stepline',
        width: 3,
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      markers: {
        size: 0,
        hover: {
          sizeOffset: 6,
        },
      },
      xaxis: xaxis,
      yaxis: [
        { show: false, logarithmic: true },
        { show: false, logarithmic: true },
        { show: false, logarithmic: true },
      ],
      tooltip: {
        y: [
          {
            title: {
              formatter: (val) => val,
            },
          },
          {
            title: {
              formatter: (val) => val,
            },
          },
          {
            title: {
              formatter: (val) => val,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      grid: {
        borderColor: '#f1f1f1',
        xaxis: { lines: { show: true } },
        yaxis: { lines: { show: true } },
      },
    },
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full h-[400px]">
      <ReactApexChart
        options={chartOptions.options}
        series={series}
        type="line"
        height={400}
      />
    </div>
  )
}


....
....
....


function index() {
    ...
    return (
        ...
        <RenderChart series={series} xaxis={xaxis} />
        ...
    )
    ...
}
```

Series are a dynamic data field.

As you can see from the below images, the background changed automatically when series data changed.
How can I resolve this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4T9H.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNmya.png)

```
options: {
      chart: { zoom: { enabled: false }, background: 'transparent' },
      stroke: {
           ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I had same issue with apexChart and I couldn't solve it and finally got forced to use trick to rerender chart to fix this issue

I use state to mount and unmount chart and useEffect to set state after data is changed

like this :

```
  const [isChartLoaded, setIsChartLoaded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    if (isMounted) {
      setIsChartLoaded(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsChartLoaded(true);
      }, 10);
    }
    return () => {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [props.data]);

{isChartLoaded && <RenderChart series={series} xaxis={xaxis} />}
```

I know this is not the best way but fixed my problem. hopefully helps you

Comment: Why did you use `if` statement below `let isMounted=true;`?

Comment: It just for optimization, not related to your issue, you can remove it

Comment: How does it works? Could you explain in more details? I think, `let isMounted=true;` is unnecessary.

Comment: that's right, it's unnecessary. when you set state in useEffect react will throw a warning in browser for memory usage, in this way no warning will be shown